# Canned beans contain no liquid?

Tags: food-safety, beans

I recently opened two cans of pinto beans from the same brand (whole foods organic). One can looked perfectly normal with a fair amount of liquid and no visible beans until drained.

The second can however was quite dry. The beans looked hydrated and cooked, but there was almost no excess liquid in the can.

Any idea what caused this? Would these be safe? I threw them out, but curious for the future.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You should have contacted the manufacturer; they would need the batch number to test. No-one else can guess.

Comment: also go to the store where you bought them; they will refund them and probably pull them out.

Comment: Went to the store and they refunded me but did not pull product as was assured they are all tested coming out.

There was no number on the can, but called a number the customer service store person gave me and they took down a complaint and said they would notify purchasing.

Answer (score 8):

You were right to throw them out, no liquid was a sign that something went wrong in processing and therefore a safety concern. When it doubt, throw it out!